# how to select the second <p> element using Xpath

Tags: xpath, rselenium

I am trying to scrape full reviews from [this](http://www.holidayiq.com/Holiday-Inn-Gem-Park-Ooty-hotel-2568.html) webpage. (Full reviews - after clicking the 'Read More' button). This I am doing using RSelenium. I am able to select and extract text from the first `<p>` element, using the code

```
reviewNodes <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//p[@id][1]")
```

which is for less text review.

But not able to extract full text reviews using the code

```
reviewNodes <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//p[@id][2]")
```

or

```
reviewNodes <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//p[@itemprop = 'reviewBody']")
```

It shows blank list elements. I don't know what is wrong. Please help me..

Comment: What does the first query return? Is it a single node or a collection? I'd expect, based on the page structure, it would retrieve a collection of all `p` elements whose `id` attribute starts with `"lessReviewContent"`, as those are first `<p>` children of their parents. Am I right?

Comment: yes... you are right... it retrieves the collection.

Comment: even when I type the xpath query "//p[@id][2]" in the "xpath helper" chrome extension, it retrieves the intended text. But the same xpath is not working in the code. Can't think about the reason....

Answer (score 0):

Drop the double slash and try to use the explicit `descendant` axis:

```
/descendant::p[@id][2]
```

(see the note from W3C document on XPath I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107948/733637))

Answer (score 0):

As you're dealing with a list, you should first find the list items, e.g. using CSS selector

```
div.srm
```

Based on these elements, you can then search on inside the list items, e.g. using CSS selector

```
p[itemprop='reviewBody']
```

Of course you can also do it in 1 single expression, but that is not quite as neat imho:

```
div.srm p[itemprop='reviewBody']
```

Or in XPath (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
//div[@class='srm']//p[@itemprop='reviewBody']
```

If neither of these work for you, then the problem must be somewhere else.