# Using XPath to add elements to mutiple elements doesn't work as intended

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My logic goes as follows: I want to find the first element that misses a given attribute, add the attribute and then find the next element which misses the element, add it and so fourth.

I find the first element missing the amount attribute in the following way:

```
    private XmlNode GetFirstElementWithoutAmount()
            {
                string productXPathQuery = "//XML/Products";
                XmlNodeList productList = ParentXmlDocument.SelectNodes(productXPathQuery);
                foreach (XmlNode element in productList)
                {
                    string passengerXPathQuery = "//XML/Products[ID=" + element.FirstChild.InnerText + "]/Amount";
                    var amount = element.SelectSingleNode(passengerXPathQuery);
                    if (amount == null)
                    {
                        return element;
                    }
                }

                return null;
     }
```

When I've found the first element missing the attribute, the amount is added in the following way:

```
private XmlNode GetOrCreateChildXMLNode(string NewNodeName, XmlNode ParentXMLNode)
        {

            if (ParentXMLNode == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            XmlNode NewXMLNode = ParentXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("//" + NewNodeName);
            if (NewXMLNode == null)
            {
                NewXMLNode = ParentXmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, NewNodeName, string.Empty);
                ParentXMLNode.AppendChild(NewXMLNode);
            }

            return NewXMLNode;
        }
```

The problems is, that it only adds to the first element, and then the first function always returns the second element, even though there's more elements to come? Any ideas why this is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053928/do-double-slash-in-xpath-predicate-work-the-same-as-in-the-path-itself is more or less canonical answer to "why when I search from the root (using `//`) it always finds the same node"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already inside `//XML/Products` during your `foreach` loop. Point directly to **subnode**.

```
string passengerXPathQuery = "./Amount";
```

Comment: What about the ID then?

Comment: You don't need the ID, because you are already selecting everything in /products.

Comment: It iterates the element all good, but only appends to the first. It looks like it thinks it's already added when processing the following.

Comment: will you able to share your sample xml?

Comment: It seems like amount doesn't get reset. So it only return the element processing the first node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203711/discussion-between-recusiwe-and-).